# Correct format of PHP if block

Tags: php, if-statement

Complete PHP noob here with an error returning because of a big nested `if` block. The error varies as I change the code, but it is always to do with the `if` statement. What is the correct way to do this statement?

Here is the incorrect `if` block:

```
if(!empty($_GET['x2'])) and (!empty($_GET['x'])) and (!empty($_GET['num']))
    {
    $xsqrd = $_GET['x2'];
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    $num = $_GET['num'];
    if(($xsqrd*2)==0.0)
    {
    print $errdivzero;
    }
    else if(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))
    {
    print $errsqrtmin1;
    }
    else
    {
    $ans1 = (-$x)+(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))/(2*$xsqrd);
    $ans2 = (-$x)-(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))/(2*$xsqrd);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Wasn't this answered a minute ago in [PHP logical AND operator error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309456/php-logical-and-operator-error)?

Comment: that's my question too, and that is about the statement, not the block

Comment: Is this question about the stuff inside `{...}`?

Comment: The obvious problem with this block is the syntax error in the brackets. What other specific problem do you have with this code?

Comment: Terminology: `()` = parentheses, `[]` = square brackets, `{}` = curly braces.

Comment: _"The error varies as I change the code"_ - so what errors are you getting?

Comment: Regarding the code block, use an editor that indents automatically, it will help you see the structure. It's impossible to tell what's going on with everything lined up like you posted.

Comment: @TomWalters just syntax errors to do with the if block such as "unexpected '{' on line 32"

Comment: Then this is evidentially purely to do with incorrect syntax - go through your code and ensure that for every `(`, `{` and `[` you have the corresponding `)`, `}` and `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if(!empty($_GET['x2']) && !empty($_GET['x']) && !empty($_GET['num']))
    {
        $xsqrd = $_GET['x2'];
        $x = $_GET['x'];
        $num = $_GET['num'];
        if(($xsqrd*2)==0.0)
        {
            print $errdivzero;
        }
        else if(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))
        {
            print $errsqrtmin1;
        }
        else
        {
            $ans1 = (-$x)+(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))/(2*$xsqrd);
            $ans2 = (-$x)-(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))/(2*$xsqrd);
        }
    }
```

You have extra `(` in `if` condition and also you declared `and` which is not php function. you need to replace `and` with `&&`.

**Now it's working fine without any error message.**

Comment: Sidenote: `And` is legal; has just a lower precedence than `&&`, but here is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($_GET['x2']) && (!empty($_GET['x']) && (!empty($_GET['num']))
 //                  ^ extra bracket         ^ extra bracket
{
    $xsqrd = $_GET['x2'];
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    $num = $_GET['num'];
    if(($xsqrd*2)==0.0)
    {
      print $errdivzero;
    }
    else if(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))
    {
      print $errsqrtmin1;
    }
    else
    {
      $ans1 = (-$x)+(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))/(2*$xsqrd);
      $ans2 = (-$x)-(sqrt(pow($x,2)-(4*$xsqrd*$num)))/(2*$xsqrd);
    }
 }
```

You had extra closing brackets at the position highlighted above. Also replace `and` with `&&`

Comment: i now get error: unexpected '{' on line 32

Answer (score 0):

Well let's check your brackets:

```
if(!empty($_GET['x2'])) and (!empty($_GET['x'])) and (!empty($_GET['num']))
  ^                   ^
```

The second highlighted bracket closes the `if` statement - this will cause an error, you should remove unnecessary brackets like so::

```
if(!empty($_GET['x2']) and !empty($_GET['x']) and !empty($_GET['num']))
```

In future you should carefully check that for each opening bracket the closing bracket is where you expect it to be, and don't go overboard with the number of brackets.

Comment: he shouldn't add opening parenthesis, he should remove extraneous closing parens.

Comment: You're now missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: Indeed, updated the answer